# angular5:ngFor works only in second button click

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

My scenario as follows

1) When the user enters a keyword in a text field and clicks on the search icon it will initiate an HTTP request to get the data.

2)Data is rendered in HTML with ngFor

The problem is on the first click the data is not rendered in HTML but I am getting the HTTP response properly, and the data rendered only on second click.

**component.ts**

```
export class CommerceComponent implements OnInit {


  private dealList = [];

  //trigger on search icon click
  startSearch(){

     //http service call
     this.getDeals();
  }

  getDeals(){

     this.gatewayService.searchDeals(this.searchParams).subscribe(
      (data:any)=>{
        this.dealList = data.result;
        console.log("Deal list",this.dealList);
      },
      (error)=>{
         console.log("Error getting deal list",error);
         this.dealList = [];
         alert('No deals found');
      }
    );
  }

}
```

**Service.ts**

```
searchDeals(data){

   var fd = new FormData();
   fd.append('token',this.cookieService.get('token'));
   fd.append('search',data.keyword);

   return this.http.post(config.url+'hyperledger/queryByParams',fd);

}
```

**HTML**

```
//this list render only on second click
<div class="deal1"  *ngFor="let deal of dealList">
     {{deal}}
 </div>
```

**UPDATE**

click bind html code

```
 <div class="search-input">
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchParams.keyword" class="search" placeholder="" autofocus>
          <div class="search-icon" (click)="startSearch()">
            <img src="assets/images/search.png">
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Post your code where you are binding the 'click' event to the StartSearch() function

Comment: when you log the ```this.dealList``` in first click whats the result?

Comment: @Thangadurai updated my question

Comment: do you see the console.log("Deal list"... on the first button click? I tried it in an angular project of mine but (interestingly enought) it worked fine.

Comment: @fatemefazli it will log the result on first click

Comment: @ManuelManhart yeah i am getting the deallist on console in the first click

Comment: did you try to use an Observable? just a wild guess. If you need code, I can post the neccessary changes for that.

Comment: @ManuelManhart not yet

Comment: @iambatman will you need code for it or can you adapt it by yourself?

Comment: @ManuelManhart yes i need

Comment: what's the result if you call service directly in ```startSearch()``` ?

Comment: @fatemefazli i am getting the http response

Comment: instead of assigning the returned value to the array, can you try with push. `this.dealList.push(data.result);`

Comment: Try to clear the dealList before fire you'r observable like **this.dealList  = []** and also add *ngIf="dealList " in the tag which you have *ngFor. please tell me the result.

Comment: when i try ` this.dealList = of([]);` the list is not rendered anymore

Comment: can you post a full example somewhere like plnkr? it is pretty much a guessing game without being able to reproduce the problem

Comment: @ManuelManhart but the http requests are not open

Comment: they shouldnt matter, it sould be enough to call eg. https://google.com/ and in the subscribe method put some dummy data into the array.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Angular official tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#display-the-message-from-heroservice), you could have problems if you bind a private property to a template:

> Angular only binds to *public* component properties.

Probably, setting the property `dealList` to public will solve the problem.

Comment: god answer but i tried most of hist code fragments in an angular project of mine and it worked (with private). Was surprised as well :-)

Comment: Depends on your Angular version, if you use AOT compiling as default you could have troubles

Comment: We'd need to reproduce the bug to understand it better

Comment: tried with this  ` public dealList = [];` but still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.dealList = Object.assign({},data.result);
```

Better do this inside the service.

By default, the angular engine renders the view only when it recognizes a change in data.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "private" from your dealList variable. That declaration makes your component variable available only during compile time.

Another problem: you are implementing OnInit in yout component but you are not using ngOnInit. Angular is suposed to throw an error in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to switch to observable:

I marked my changes with CHANGE

component.ts

```
// CHANGE
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
// MISSING IMPORT
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

export class CommerceComponent implements OnInit {
    // CHANGE
    private dealList: Observable<any[]>; // you should replace any with your object type, eg. string, User or whatever

    //trigger on search icon click
    startSearch() {
       //http service call
        this.getDeals();
    }

    getDeals() {
        this.gatewayService.searchDeals(this.searchParams).subscribe(
            (data:any)=>{
                // CHANGE
                this.dealList = of(data.result);
                console.log("Deal list",this.dealList);
            },
            (error)=>{
                console.log("Error getting deal list",error);
                // CHANGE
                this.dealList = of([]);
                alert('No deals found');
            }
        );
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- CHANGE -->
<div class="deal1"  *ngFor="let (deal | async) of dealList">
    {{deal}}
</div>
```

Comment: I wrote this code without testing, if it does not compile or work correctly let me know & I will fix it.

Comment: let me try your answer

Comment: Updated the answer with the MISSING IMPORT ;-)

Comment: I got another one `Parser Error: Unexpected token (,`

Comment: finally it works with this `let deal of dealList | async` but i got the same problem:)